# How do I connect to ProxMox API via Postman?

Tags: postman, proxmox

I've been trying to connect to the Proxmox API via Postman so I can explore it further, but can't seem to connect.  I keep getting `401 No Ticket` despite getting  the TICKET and CSRF via curl and plugging those into:

- Params and running via GET
- Authorization as API Key, Bearer, etc

I've already scoured https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_API and https://pve.proxmox.com/pve-docs/api-viewer/index.html as well as Googling and checking SO.  Nothing seems to provide a useful solution.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found inspiriation at https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/remote-spice-access-without-using-web-manager.16561/.

The solution to this particular problem is to set a cookie in Postman called PVEAuthCookie and set it's value to the TICKET.

[image: Postman Interface, pointing out Cookies option]

Most of you probably know this, but just in case... you need to define a domain first.  If you copy and paste, **don't include the port number**. after that click the domain, add cookie and fill in your information.
[image: Cookies Interface]

I know I answered my own question here, but I'd love other responses if you have a more streamlined way to do this.  Especially how to get the ticket process streamlined.